# The "lower bound" will reverse the variance of a type, but why?

Tags: scala, type-systems, variance, lower-bound

In [scala specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), there is some description about the variance and lower bound:

> The variance position of the lower bound of a type declaration or type parameter is the opposite of the variance position of the type declaration or parameter.

Which is on page 44.

I can get some idea but I can't explain it clearly. Could you give me some detail explanation on it?

Answer (score 2):

Basically, lower bounds must be invariant or contravariant. Compare these, which compile:

```
class Good1[-A, B >: A]
class Good2[-A, B >: A]
```

And this, which doesn't:

```
class Bad1[+A, B >: A]
```

If `Bad1` was allowed, you could do:

```
val worse: Bad1[Any, Int] = new Bad1[Int, Int]
```

Which would imply that `Int >: Any`, which is false.